# unicode in NSLocalizedString

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

To have to words that cannot be separated by line breaks, I want to exchange a whitespace with `\u{a0}` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25395011/386738)).

My problem is, that Unicode characters do not seem to work with `NSLocalizedString`.

This is what I tried:

```
"myKey" = "ababa\u{a0}ababa"; // results in "ababau{a0}ababa"
"myKey" = "ababa\u00a0ababa"; // results in "ababau00a0ababa"
"myKey" = "ababa\\u{a0}ababa";// results in "ababa\\u{a0}ababa"
```

I use `NSLocalizedString("myKey", tableName: "myTable", comment: String)` to load the string (I load it from a version specific LocalizedString)

Comment: Try entering it literally.

Comment: @matt I'd prefer not to, because it is a special type of whitespace, and nobody would notice it

Comment: Try \U00A0 instead of \u{a0}

Comment: Yes, it is `\Unnnn` in the strings files.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks a lot