# How to make attributed string never wrap?

Tags: nsattributedstring, appkit, nstextfield

I am using NSAttributedString for my NSTextView for showing a hyperlink along with some other string. when my other string is long the link string gets wrapped (i.e that's the link string breaks and moves to next line). How to avoid it.

I will provide a sample code of what I have done:

```
            let displayedStringValue ="Learn More"
            let url = URL(string: displayedStringValue)
            let linkRange = NSRange(location: detail.count, length: displayedStringValue.count)
            let fullTextString = "This is sample String" + displayedStringValue
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullTextString)
            let learnMoreFontColor = NSColor.Red
            let linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .foregroundColor: learnMoreFontColor,
            ]
            attributedString.addAttributes(linkAttributes, range: linkRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: url, range: linkRange)
            
            let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)

            let contentFontColor = NSColor.Red
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
            attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: range)
            let contentRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: detail.length)
            attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: contentFontColor, range: contentRange)
            myTextField.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
            myTextField.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedString)
```

When the contents of detailsstring is longer learn more string is clipping. How to avoid this?

Comment: What should happen instead of wrapping or clipping?

Comment: My hyperlint text should wrap in between. either it should be along the same line as sample string or it has to go to new line completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing line breaks in part of an NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393231/preventing-line-breaks-in-part-of-an-nsattributedstring)

Comment: can this be applied for nsattributedstring?

Comment: Probably not, `NSAttributedString` is immutable. You have to convert to `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Comment: the problem is it has to work with localization also it should not be selectable and hyperlink should work @Willeke

Comment: Can't you replace the spaces in the string before adding it to the `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: I have found the solution for it.

Comment: I have used special characters  when the length of character is more than what i found in manual calculation